# How to Store Previous Value Of Loop in variable

Tags: android, json

JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(response);

```
    ArrayList<Level2_Women> alUser = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray parentArray = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("categories");

    StringBuffer finalBufferData = new StringBuffer();

    for (int j = 0; j <parentArray.length(); j++) {


            JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(j);

            user.setCategory(finalObject.getString("category"));
            String catid = finalObject.getString("category_id");



    }
    return user;
}
```

I am Using this loop.In my Loop there are 12 elements,But its print only last value.How i can print all element in Listview?

Comment: put return user; inside loop. Since return value will only be executed when loop ends with last value .you are getting last value

Comment: yes ,then what i can do for print all values ?

Comment: DeshMukha  Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error 1:** You are always returning `user` object instead of list `alUser`.
**Error 2:** Inside `for` loop, you didn't added individual `user` to list `alUser`.

**Update your method as below:**

```
public ArrayList<Level2_Women> YOUR_METHOD_NAME(String response)
{
    // User List
    ArrayList<Level2_Women> alUser = new ArrayList<>();

    JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray parentArray = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("categories");

    // Not used!
    StringBuffer finalBufferData = new StringBuffer();

    for (int j = 0; j <parentArray.length(); j++) {

        JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(j);

        // User
        Level2_Women user = new Level2_Women();

        // Set user values
        user.setCategory(finalObject.getString("category"));

        // Not used!        
        String catid = finalObject.getString("category_id");

        // Add user to list
        alUser.add(user)
    }

    // Finally return user list
    return alUser;
}
```

**FYI**, If you are facing problem with list update then use adapter `notifyDataSetChanged()` method to update data on `ListView`/`RecyclerView`.

**Hope this will help~**

Answer (score 1):

Use list to store all values then use

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int j = 0; j <parentArray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(j);
        user.setCategory(finalObject.getString("category"));
        String catid = finalObject.getString("category_id");
        list.add(catid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Loop should Go like this:

```
   for (int j = 0; j <parentArray.length(); j++) {


        JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(j);

        user.setCategory(finalObject.getString("category"));
        String catid = finalObject.getString("category_id");
```

return user;

}
    return user will return value everytime you iterate for loop.
Since i assume you are new to java this [excelent tutorial will help you learn a lot](http://beginnersbook.com/2015/03/for-loop-in-java-with-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I guess you have an User entity

```
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int j = 0; j <parentArray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(j);
        user.setCategory(finalObject.getString("category"));
        String catid = finalObject.getString("category_id");
        userList.add(user);
}
for(String k: userList)
        {
            System.out.println(k);
        }
return userList
```